# Prime ideals in polynomial rings satisfying a particular condition

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, polynomial-rings

In the [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-03/S0002-9939-1971-0289489-0/S0002-9939-1971-0289489-0.pdf) "***Kronecker function rings and flat $D[X]$-modules***" by Arnold and Brewer it's proved the following result:

**Lemma:** Let $D$ be an integral domain. If $Q$ is a prime ideal of $D[X]$ such that $D[X]_Q$ is a valuation ring and if $(Q\cap D)D[X]\subset Q$, then $Q\cap D=\{0\}$.

I was trying to prove the above lemma, but I couldn't. Then when I read the proof given in the paper I was unable to fully understand the proof. In order to make this post self contained, let me include a sketch of such proof.

> Using the fact that $D_{Q\cap D}=D[X]_Q\cap K$ (where $K$ is the quotient field of $D$), the authors claim that it's enough to assume that $D$ is a valuation ring and $Q\cap D$ is its maximal ideal. I don't understand why.
>
> On the other hand, they find that $Q$ contains a monic polynomial $f$ such that $f\notin (Q\cap D)D[X]_Q$. I guess they are using that $(Q\cap D)D[X]\subset Q$.
>
> Then they take $y\in Q\cap D$, by the hypothesis ($D[X]_Q$ is a valuation ring) they conclude that $f\mid y$, i.e., there are $g\in D[X]$, $h\in D[X]\setminus Q$ such that $y=fg/h$. Then, if we suppose that $y\neq 0$, we get $h=f(g/y)$, thus $f\mid h$ in $K[X]$. After this, they conclude that $f\mid h$ in $D[X]$  by using theorem 8.4 of Gilmer's book "*Multiplicative Ideal Theory*".

I looked for the theorem, but I didn't find anything because I have the edition of 1996 and in such book section 8 is an "Allerlei" where the author makes additional remarks, gives further references, etc.

Basically, what I wrote above is their proof. I think we can add the following in order to show the contradiction by assuming that $y\neq 0$.

As $D[X]\setminus Q$ is a saturated multiplicatively closed subset of $D[X]$, then $f\in D[X]\setminus Q$, contradicting the fact that $f\in Q$. Hence, it must be $y=0$, i.e., $Q\cap D=\{0\}$.

Finally, I have two questions regarding the above proof.

> 1) Why can we assume that $D$ is a valuation ring and $Q\cap D$ is its maximal ideal?
>
> 2) Which theorem the authors are using in the last part of their proof, when they conclude that $f\mid h$ in $K[X]$ implies $f\mid h$ in $D[X]$?

Comment: 1) Replace $D$ by $D_{Q\cap D}$. This is a valuation ring, and $D_{Q\cap D}[X]_Q=D[X]_Q$.

Comment: 2) This seems pretty easy if one recalls that every valuation ring is gaussian.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)#Version_valid_over_any_GCD_domain

Comment: @user26857 would you like to convert your comments into an answer? :)

Comment: The OP's answer is always more important for him than anyone else answer ;) Please do this instead of me.

Comment: @user26857 well, since I'm still a beginner in commutative algebra, I'll check more carefully the arguments in order to answer my own question.